# "Method must have a return type" on a class constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Riddle me this, Batman. The section of my code is

```
public class SurveyDbModel
{
    // name of connection string for database that 
    private static readonly string _ConnStrName = "LocalDb";

    private SqlConnection Conn; 

    public SurveyModelDb ( )
    {
        this.Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[SurveyDbModel._ConnStrName].ConnectionString);
    }

}
```

and the Visual Studio error is pointing to `SurveyModelDb`. I can't tell what I'm doing wrong because my synatx seems to match [the example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx),

```
public class Taxi
{
    public bool isInitialized;
    public Taxi()
    {
        isInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no constructor in SurveyDbModel. you only have a method called SurveyModelDb

Comment: `BewareOfWrongWordsSequence`, `SequenceWordsOfBewareWrong`

Answer (score 4):

Your constructor method name needs to match your class name, otherwise the compiler thinks it's a regular method and so needs a return type.

Eg.

```
public class SurveyDbModel
{
    // name of connection string for database that 
    private static readonly string _ConnStrName = "LocalDb";

    private SqlConnection Conn; 

    public SurveyDbModel ( )
    {
        this.Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[SurveyDbModel._ConnStrName].ConnectionString);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

the constructor name `SurveyModelDb` is not matching with the class name `SurveyDbModel`..

Answer (score 2):

This `SurveyDbModel` is not the same as `SurveyModelDb`. The constructor should have the same name as of the class. `SurveyModelDb` is a method for you which you have not provided a return type.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor name should match the class name. Here the class name is 'SurveyDbModel' but the ctor is 'SurveyModelDb'.

Change `public SurveyModelDb(){}` to `public SurveyDbModel(){}`

Answer (score 2):

Obviously  **public SurveyModelDb ( )** isn't a .ctor for **SurveyDbModel**.